# Similarly structured loops with different big-O time complexities?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have a function:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i*= 2)
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    sum++;
```

From my understanding this is $O(n\log(n))$ because the inner loop runs $n$ times for every time the outer loop runs, and the outer loop is running $\log(n)$ times. Putting them together gives me $O(n\log(n))$, which I understand. However, the following loop:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = n; i > 0; i/= 2)
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)  
    sum++;
```

I see this as $O(n\log(n))$ because the outer loop is running $\log(n) + 1$ times still and the inner loop runs $n + n/2 + n/4...$ whose sum will be some coefficient $c$ times $n$. Together with the outer loop simplifying to $O(n\log(n))$ but it turns out it is actually $O(n)$ however I don't see how it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version increments `sum`
$$
\underbrace{n + n + \dots + n}_{\log n \text{ terms}} = n\log n
$$
time; the second does it
$$
\underbrace{n + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} + \dots + 1}_{\log n \text{ terms}} \leq 2n
$$
times (use the formula for a geometric series).

By the way, it's not actually *wrong* to say that the second is also $O(n\log n)$: it's just that you can give a more precise answer of $O(n)$.

Comment: Why is the last term 1 in the second summation? Also, could you please explain how the sum equals 2n in a bit more detail?

Comment: Because, at the final iteration of the outer loop, `i=1`, so the inner loop executes once, with `j=0`.

Answer (score 0):

In the second algorithm, the total number of increment operations would be $$\sum_{i=0}^{\lceil\lg n\rceil } \frac{n}{2^i}$$, which is $\leq 2n$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) Wikipedia article about infinit geometric series and the inequallity should be clearer.